# how i can get list of name of folder in firebase storage android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

[image]

How can I get list of all folder file/,R52H50TN40F/,R58H42X2DCE/...

Answer (score 3):

It's possible. Make sure you have this dependency in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1' // or later
}
```

This is how you can iterate over a list of directories and their entries:

```
listRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/");             

listRef.listAll()                                                      
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {        
        @Override                                                      
        public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {                 

            Log.d(TAG, listRef.getName());                             
            for (StorageReference prefix : listResult.getPrefixes()) { 
                Log.d(TAG, prefix.getName());                          
                // This will give you a folder name                    
                // You may call listAll() recursively on them.         
            }                                                          

            for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {      
                // All the items under listRef.                        
            }                                                          
        }                                                              
    })                                                                 
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {                    
        @Override                                                      
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {                  
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!                               
        }                                                              
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get list of all folders with the `firebase client api`

But you can combine `Firebase Functions` and `Cloud Storage bucket API`.

1. Create a firebase function [(documentation)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start)
2. Use [Firebase Bucket getFiles function](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/Bucket#getFiles)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible
[As example shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWBit.png)

First Step: add Firebase Storage Dependencies

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
}
```

Second Step :

```
storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("folders");
    storageReference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
            Log.d("Get List Ref",storageReference.getName());
            for(StorageReference prefix:listResult.getPrefixes())
            {
                Log.d("prefix",prefix.getName());
                FoldersYear.add(new FolderClass(prefix.getName()));
                Log.d("folder", String.valueOf(FoldersYear));
            }
           
      
        }

    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d("failure","failure");
        }
    });
```

Build your project and enjoy